# How to copy image from PictureBox1 to excel?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Following code copies excel chart as picture and paste it into PictureBox1.

```
Dim ExcelWbk1 As Excel.Workbook
ExcelWbk1.ActiveChart.CopyPicture(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap)
PictureBox1.Image = CType(Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
```

Now, lets do the opposite.

How to copy image from PictureBox1 and paste to the excel?

Following link may help...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172505(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim wbkMyBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim shtMySheet As Worksheet

wbkMyBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path to xls file)

xlApp.Visible = True

shtMySheet = wbkMyBook.Worksheets(1)

Clipboard.Clear()

Clipboard.SetData(Image, Me.PictureBox1.Image)

shtMySheet.Paste

wbkMyBook = Nothing
shtMySheet = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
xlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox1.Image)
ActiveSheet.Paste(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
```

Comment: Worksheet.Paste has two optional parameters, first is the Destination 'Range' and second is Link 'Boolean'.